# How to Automate pressing Done button using Appium python

Tags: python-appium

[Unable to automate Done button press(Shown in screenshot-click on this link) using Appium Python. Need assistance on this please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3O44.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the id of the checkmark using uiautomatorviewer and click
  it.
- Using the back key after entering the value may work(**driver.navigate().back()** for java, I guess for python **driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);**)

Answer (score 0):

Key presses on appium are done by

`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)

- code is 66 for KEYCODE_ENTER, so

`driver.press_keycode(66)`

Comment: I tried the code driver.press_keycode(66) but it didnt work.

Comment: This code solved the issue - driver.execute_script('mobile: performEditorAction', {'action': 'done'})